# VBA Multicolumn reference within table

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set a table in VBA, however, I only want to set the range to be specific columns within the table. I can't seem to find out how to do it. Everything I search for seems to return excel table referencing and it doesn't appear to be the correct syntax for VBA. This is what I have but I get a runtime error '9': subscript out of range.

```
Set Contact = Worksheets("Tables").ListObjects("Table1[[Column2]:[Column8]]")
```

edit: I don't think my question was clear. I am trying to reference a certain range within a table because I am using a vlookup to find the data I am looking for. I am referencing the information in column two and get the information in column 8 to set to a variable. So I am trying to set the listobject to be a table within a bigger table of sorts.

Comment: Have you tried: `Set Contact = Worksheets("Tables").Range("B:H")` or `Set Contact = Worksheets("Tables").Columns(2:8)`?

Comment: That does, but how does it change from ListObjects? All my other tables worked fine when set as a ListObject? Is it because I was only trying to reference part of the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `ListObjects("TableName")` to reference the whole table.  Then `ListColumns("ColumnHeading")` to reference specific columns within the table, where "ColumnHeading" is the actual heading name in the table (or `ListColumns(#)` where `#` is the index number of the column).  Then `DataBodyRange` to reference the range of the column data.

Rather than `VLookup` it would be better to use `Match` to find the row number, and a `Range.Cells` to get the result.

Something like this

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Dim SearchRange As Range
    Dim LookupRange As Range
    Dim SearchTerm As Variant
    Dim LookupItem As Variant
    Dim idx As Variant

    Set lo = Worksheets("Tables").ListObjects("Table1")
    Set SearchRange = lo.ListColumns("Column2").DataBodyRange
    Set LookupRange = lo.ListColumns("Column8").DataBodyRange

    SearchTerm = "YourSearchTerm"
    idx = Application.Match(SearchTerm, SearchRange, 0)
    If Not IsError(idx) Then
        LookupItem = LookupRange.Cells(idx, 1)
        ' use the result as you wish
        Debug.Print LookupItem
    Else
        ' SearchTerm not found.  What now?
    End If

    'For completeness, heres how to reference a range of columns
    Dim VLookupRange As Range
    Set VLookupRange = lo.Parent.Range(lo.ListColumns("Column2").DataBodyRange, lo.ListColumns("Column8").DataBodyRange)
    Debug.Print VLookupRange.Address

End Sub
```